# Android returning to main activity to GLSurfaceView activity and back to main

Tags: android, android-intent

On the main activity I have a button that brings me into another activity when I press back button I would like to return to that main activity?  Should I just do same thing that I did for other activity but using a intent to go back to main activity or is the main activity onPause and I should use another method to un pause it?

This when i click the button in main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{



    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>(grid_size);
    CustomGridViewAdapter customGridAdapter;
    private GLSurfaceView glView; // Use subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)



    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
         setContentView(glView);*/      


        customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.button_item, gridArray, str_arr,column_width,column_height);


        gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);


        enableDisableView(gridView, false);

    }

    @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;


} 



 @Override
          public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            // action with ID action_refresh was selected
            case R.id.action_refresh:
              /*Toast.makeText(this, "Refresh selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                 .show();*/

                /*// Allocate a custom subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)
                glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
                setContentView(glView);  // Set View (NEW)private GLSurfaceView glView;  */         

                 Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyGLActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

          break;
            // action with ID action_settings was selected
            case R.id.action_settings:
              Toast.makeText(this, "Settings selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                  .show();
              break;
            default:
              break;
            }

            return true;
          }

        protected void onResume() 
        {
            super.onResume();
            customGridAdapter.counter = 0;
        }

        protected void onPause() 
        {


            /*if (customGridAdapter.scheduleTaskExecutorSession.isShutdown()
                    && customGridAdapter.scheduleTaskExecutorSession1.isShutdown()) 
            {
                // do nothing
            }
            else 
            {

                customGridAdapter.scheduleTaskExecutorSession.shutdown();
                customGridAdapter.scheduleTaskExecutorSession1.shutdown();
            }*/

            super.onPause();
         }
```

The other activity back button code

```
    public class MyGLActivity extends Activity {
     private GLSurfaceView glView;  // Use subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Allocate a custom subclass of GLSurfaceView (NEW)
        glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this, null);
        setContentView(glView);  // Set View (NEW)
     }
       @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
  super.onBackPressed();
  finish();     
}
 @Override
 protected void onPause() {

     //super.onPause();
    //glView.onPause();

 }

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    glView.onResume();
 }
```

GLSurfaceView.java

```
public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
   MyGLRenderer renderer;    // Custom GL Renderer

   // For touch event
   private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 180.0f / 320.0f;
   private float previousX;
   private float previousY;

   // Constructor - Allocate and set the renderer
   public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
      renderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
      this.setRenderer(renderer);
      // Request focus, otherwise key/button won't react
      this.requestFocus();  
      this.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
   }

   // Handler for key event
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent evt) {
      switch(keyCode) {
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:   // Decrease Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY -= 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:  // Increase Y-rotational speed
            renderer.speedY += 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:     // Decrease X-rotational speed
            renderer.speedX -= 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:   // Increase X-rotational speed 
            renderer.speedX += 0.1f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A:           // Zoom out (decrease z)
            renderer.z -= 0.2f;
            break;
         case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z:           // Zoom in (increase z)
            renderer.z += 0.2f;
            break;
      }
      return true;  // Event handled
   }

   // Handler for touch event
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent evt) {
      float currentX = evt.getX();
      float currentY = evt.getY();
      float deltaX, deltaY;
      switch (evt.getAction()) {
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // Modify rotational angles according to movement
            deltaX = currentX - previousX;
            deltaY = currentY - previousY;
            renderer.angleX += deltaY * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
            renderer.angleY += deltaX * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR;
      }
      // Save current x, y
      previousX = currentX;
      previousY = currentY;
      return true;  // Event handled
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the super.onBackPressed(); should be the first ligne

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed()
 {
  super.onBackPressed();
  finish();     
}
```

Comment: I don't want to close it. I want to return back to the main activity?

Comment: yes the finish() just close the second activity so that your main activity show up again

Comment: I put this in code above but it doesn't work. The back button won't do anything?

Comment: do you make like this in your second activity  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}

Comment: Sorry doesn't seem to work either.  Is there a problem with using GLSurfaceView?

Comment: I can't even get it to print out a log!?

Comment: when you press the back button what happen exactly?

Comment: nothing. Not even log prints out when I press back button.

Comment: can you just delete the onBackPressed() function from your code and test, it should by default finish the second activity

Comment: I deleted onBackPressed from the GLSurfaceActivity and same result both on emulator and on phone.  It does nothing. It must be how I'm using intent to call the activity.

Comment: I added more code to give more of complete view of code.

Comment: Main activity is using gridview with adapter, maybe it can't go back to that?!

Answer (score 0):

In android Activities are 'layered' on top of each other. If you didn't call `finish()` on the calling activity, pressing the back button will bring you back to it.

So the good news is: you don't have to do anything at all. The standard behavior of android will take you back to the Main activity (If you didn't kill it)

Comment: Its not working when i got into the other activity the back button doesn't do anything?

Comment: It should, so you are changing something in the default flow. Could you post some code?

Comment: It is not needed to override the OnBackButtonPressed() method. Actually, it should be avoided to mess with the default behavior, since it will make the user experience worse. I don't see where it goes wrong in you code. Are you sure you are not calling finish() on the main activity?

Comment: I'm thinking it might have to do GLSurfaceView?

Comment: I can't even get it to print out a log!?

Comment: I don't have experience with the GLSurfaceView, but it seems weird that a View will override the default behavior. I also can't find anything special in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html). Does your app crash when you press back or does it do nothing at all?

Comment: does nothing. I can't even get log to print out when I press back button. Weird. I missing something probably conceptually.

Comment: In some weird way your GLSurfaceView probably consumes the onBackPressed() method. Strange and unwanted behavior. OnKeyDown() is probably not consumed. If it works, use it, but I would be curious why it doesn't work in the default way.

Comment: It must not being put on the stack. My guess its because i'm using gridview with adapter in the main activity and may do some kind of garbage collecting.

Comment: all your activities are on the stack, otherwise they won't be displayed. A GridView with adapter won't interfere with this. Have you looked at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the function when the back key is tapped and return to any activity you want :

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
    {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is the only one that works. onBackPress doesn't even recognize? Is a API or platform issue?

Comment: I cannot say if that's an API or platform issue. Mark it as answer if that solved your problem to help others. Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may be referring to the android back stack. When you start another activity, the new activity is pushed on the top of the previous one. The previous activity remains in stack but it's stopped. If you press the back button the activity that is on top is destroyed and your previous activity resumes. So, the answer is no, you don't need another mehod or anything.

You can find more information about it in 
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Its not working when i got into the other activity the back button doesn't do anything?